# Why my Python program recognizes the number one as Prime number?

Tags: python

I know the following codes are not optimal and I wrote them just for my own training. But I don't know why the number one (1) is recognized as the prime number.
Please help me!

```
n=input ('Enter number: ')
def prime ():           
     global n    
     try:
       n=int (n)           
       for I in range (2, n):
            if n==1 or n%I==0:
              print (n,"is not prime ")  
              break           
       else:
            print (n,"is Prime")
       if True:     
           n=input ('enters number: ')
           prime ()
     except:
           n=input ('Please enter a number not a word: ')
           prime ()        
prime ()
```

Comment: By what logic do you think your code would not indicate that 1 is prime?

Comment: `range(2,1)` is empty, so the `else` clause will trigger if n = 1. Just special case 1 (and 2).

Comment: thanks all, @BuddyBobIII sorry.. I formatted.@khelwood.@SuperStormer yes, thank you it the problem..but how to fix it?

Comment: @HiwaSadeghpour This is not your only problem, there are multiple issues with your code such as recursively calling itself within the `except` clause and the `if True:` statement that does not make any sense. There are many good examples for finding primes. Why don't you start by studying a few of them?

Comment: just insert an if statement to handle the special case of 1 and 2 at the top, and in an else pending statement add your for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your first if statement is not evaluated when n = 1 because range (2,1) is empty. So it moves on to the else statement and prints 1 as prime.  To fix this, you should expand your range to (0,n) and redo your if statement as follows:

```
n=input ('Enter number: ')
def prime ():
     global n
     try:
       n=int (n)
       for I in range (0, n):
            if n == 1 or (I > 1 and  n%I == 0):
              print (n,"is not prime ")
              break
       else:
            print (n,"is Prime")
       if True:
           n=input ('enters number: ')
           prime ()
     except:
           n=input ('Please enter a number not a word: ')
           prime ()
prime ()

#output:
Enter number: 3
3 is Prime
enters number: 2
2 is Prime
enters number: 1
1 is not prime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way

```
n=input ('Enter number: ')
def prime ():           
    global n    
    try:
        n=int (n) 

        if n == 1:
            print('n is not prime')
        else:        
            for I in range (2, n):
                if n%I==0:
                    print (n,"is not prime ")  
                    break           
            else:
                print (n,"is Prime")
    except:
        n=input ('Please enter a number not a word: ')
prime ()
```

Comment: 2 is a prime number.